# how to generate id no for each json element

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am having a json output like following. I want to give incremental id for each node and decode. Please help me.

```
[{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DND","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"AIRTEL"},{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DND","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"AIRTEL"},{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"1.00","messageStatus":"DELIVRD","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"AIRTEL"},{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"1.00","messageStatus":"DND REJECTED","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"VODAFONE"}]
```

I want output like

```
id:1
messageStatus:DND
id:2
messageStatus:DND
id:3
messageStatus:DELIVERD
id:4
messageStatus:DND
```

Comment: Not clear. What is the code you are using to generate the json output ? And where do you need to add the incremented value ?

Comment: I am using curl for retrieving a json. but in that json format i am not getting any id so i want to know how can give id to each node of json @zeflex

Comment: Do you mean using PHP to parse the JSON string and assign them with IDs ?

Comment: OK, so you want to enumerate each of the items in the JSON array.  Show us what you have tried.

Comment: exactly i am not able to understand how to do it.. so please help me@ frasertweedale

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '[{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DND","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"AIRTEL"},{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DND","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"AIRTEL"},{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"1.00","messageStatus":"DELIVRD","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"AIRTEL"},{"message":"Test+sms","sender":"EXECUT","billcredit":"1.00","messageStatus":"DND REJECTED","sendondate":"2015-04-22 15:22:00","provider":"VODAFONE"}]
';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Here you will get the Ids of each objects. I cannot post it as comment as it's too long.

Comment: do you mean `json_decode($json, true)`, which will convert the `$json` to an array...?

Comment: It depends how you wanna use the datas after the json_decode as you didn't tell it in your question.

Comment: i am sorry i couldnt  make you understand. I want output like:
id:1 messageStatus:DND id:2 messageStatus:DND id:3 messageStatus:DELIVERD id:4 messageStatus:DND

Comment: i get the array by means of json_decode($json, true) but want serializing the output @Raptor

Comment: Do a foreach loop in order to generate the output according to your needs.

Comment: @Arindam you can always loop through the array / object to format your output